# Static member of singleton vs static local members vs local members

Tags: c#, .net, static

I have a singleton static class that contains settings, `Settings.Instance.MemberName`.
This class is in GlobalSettings project inside a solution that contains several projects.

All projects are compiled as DLL and used by an external Windows Service process.
In one project in this solution, I have 100-200 instances of `ClassA`, this class is used for polling data from device using a Network Socket.
The polling is done with certain logic, And I use settings from `Settings.Instance`,
e.g for settings is sleep time between polling.

```
socket.Send(..);
Thread.Sleep(Settings.Instance.SleepBetweenSendAndReceive);
socket.Receive(..);
```

My question is, What is better to do ?

1. All instance should call Settings.Instance.MaxNetworkRetries directly as above.
2. In ClassA constructor, I should load all settings to a local **static** private members

   > (Thread.Sleep(_sleepBetweenSendAndReceive);)
3. In ClassA constructor, I should load all settings to a local private members

   > (Thread.Sleep(_sleepBetweenSendAndReceive);)

What would give best performance? Or maybe there is no difference at all.

Comment: Have you experienced any performance issues connected to that code? And maybe even more important question: is there any possibility that `Settings.Instance.MemberName` value changes during program execution?

Comment: They are not going to change. I have encountered performance issues during the work with the socket, I am doing the best i can in order to make this code work better, I know this is minor Improvement, if at all.. im just curious what is better, Educational purpose also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine there are any performance issues there if all you want to do is `Sleep()` anyway.

When network communication is involved, the network usually is the bottleneck, and the overhead of a property call is neglectable.

If you want to increase performance in your application, you could remove the `Sleep()`, and either block on `Receive()` or receive data asynchronously (if you're not sure you're going to receive data).

But in the end, accessing a field in the same class should be faster than a property of a property of a static class. You could write a sample project without network communication, and time the difference.

Comment: I have solved the network issues, at least a part of them.. this question regards calling static members of my class, private members of my class or static members from another dll that was load to the same process..

Comment: @ilansch Aaccessing members from another class has some overhead vs from the same class, but it does not matter if that's from a different dll. All I really know is that you usually won't _notice_ any performance difference. If you want numbers, it's easy to benchmark.